# X-platform reentrant wcstok()?

Tags: c++, gcc, cross-platform, reentrancy

Right now I'm looking for a reentrant version of `wcstok()` that is known by GCC and other compilers (if there's any).

So far I use `wcstok_s()` but that one is MSVC only and I need to compile the code on other platforms as well. While some pages suggest `wcstok_r()` I couldn't find it in my GCC headers. Other (man)pages mention `strtok_s()` without a specific wide char version but mention it's said to be used for for multibyte strings only(?).

So, I'm open for suggestions. Writing my own wrapper/version would be a last way out solution only.

Edit for aschepler:
Sample code that doesn't compile due to `too many arguments` - should compile despite being pointless:

```
#include <cwchar> // includes wchar.h as well

int main(void)
{
    wchar_t *a, *b, *c;
    wcstok(a, b, &c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Added a workaround now to solve this issue - seems like C89 defines a 2 parameter wcstok and the 3 parameter one was added some time later in the 90's ... overall very confusing, especially due to it being inconsistent in GCC as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `wcstok` specified by C89 (and therefore C++) is reentrant and has the same signature and essentially the same behavior as Microsoft's `wcstok_s`.  `wcstok` should be declared in `<wchar.h>` and/or `<cwchar>`.

```
wchar_t* wcstok(wchar_t* s, const wchar_t* delim, wchar_t** ptr);
```

But it looks like Microsoft's `wcstok` has an incorrect signature.

So maybe you can use `#ifdef _WINDOWS` (rather than `#ifdef _MSC_VER`) to determine which function to use, if you run into this problem even using gcc on Windows.

Comment: Any additional define required? Mine (GCC 4.5.0 on Win32) won't take 3 arguments (`error: too many arguments to function 'wchar_t* wcstok(wchar_t*, const wchar_t*)'`). Was one of the first things to try.

Comment: It's no issue with defining the right function to call. Seems like MinGW's include files provide the non-reentrant version only (checked the preprocessed code file). I could just "screw" compiling for Win32 using GCC but that doesn't sound like a clean solution I'd like. Adding a small test program I used to verify it's not my other code...

Comment: Seems to be a MinGW issue - http://uk.groups.yahoo.com/group/praat-users/message/4464